# Best Practices: Website and Database Integration

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

What are the pros and cons of different methods of including data from a database on your webpage?

From my understanding I have two options. A html page, with JavaScript (or other browser language) that fetches and includes data. A php script (or other server based program) that builds and outputs an html page with the data already included. But how am I to made the decision between the two?

Comment: Javascript is client side, PHP is server side.  You need a server side language to communicate with the database.  In other words, you still need to use something like PHP.  Javascript can be used as a complement and retrieve data from a PHP script asynchronously through AJAX.

Comment: Actually there are many other options. Eg you could create static HTML only pages with the db content, ... The difference between the two presented methods should be clear: Do you want one request (PHP) or multiple (first HTML, then various AJAX)? And: Does it even matter?

Comment: I think SO police is sleeping or relaxing. Usually these types of questions are put on hold because they are too broad or provoke debates etc. That's why people are downvoting. I don't agree with it because this is still a valid programming question. There should be a separate forum where people should be allowed to post questions like this.

Comment: I honestly don't think it is any more opinion based than any other question. Every question that gets more than a single person responding turns into a debate with alternate opinions of what the correct response is. In programming there are always multiple solutions, and asking for how to decide between them is a concrete answerable question. The problem for any question worth asking there are probably only a few people in the whole world who know the whole answer. Most people are going to have some wrong opinion mixed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always go for PHP when using a database. It is a more robust and proven technique.

Also PHP pages are protected by the server and nobody can see how the code works, they only see HTML output, whereas with Javascript anyone can see your code.

After all I don't know how JS supposed to interact with data, maybe store data in an XML page and then retrieve them, not sure. Why invent a wheel when you have PHP which is supposed to work with databases unlike JS which is designed mostly to be an improved front end functionality, unless its back end JS, but few people use JS that way.

Comment: Then how do you explain the popularity of frameworks such as AngularJS?

Comment: I think the question was about PHP vs Javascript. You can work with databases using AngularJS, but what if Javascript is disabled? Then it is of no use.

Comment: I do not think that this was the question. I read it as "output with data included vs output and fetch data dynamically"

Comment: This answer is a bit too absolute. There are several benefits to passing only data from the server to the frontend. The code that generates the data is still "hidden" in the server, and having the frontend code public shouldn't really be a problem.

Comment: I welcome you to post your own answers and give the asker a different perspective on this issue rather than criticizing my answer. I gave my point of view and I know many people will agree with it, but why not express your own view.

Comment: @ed-ta Because SO is not (primarily) for opinions. That is why the close option "primarily opinion-based" exists.